# mysql not picking up the optimal index

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Here's my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `idx_weight` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SECURITY_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL COMMENT,
  `CONS_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `EFF_DATE` date NOT NULL,
  `WEIGHT` decimal(9,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `BPK_AK` (`SECURITY_ID`,`CONS_ID`,`EFF_DATE`),
  KEY `idx_weight_ix` (`SECURITY_ID`,`EFF_DATE`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=75334536 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

For query 1:

`explain select SECURITY_ID, min(EFF_DATE) as startDate, max(EFF_DATE) as endDate from idx_weight where security_id = 1782`:

```
+----+-------------+------------+------+----------------------+---------------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type | possible_keys        | key           | key_len | ref   | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+------+----------------------+---------------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | idx_weight | ref  | BPK_AK,idx_weight_ix | idx_weight_ix | 8       | const | 887856 | Using index |
+----+-------------+------------+------+----------------------+---------------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+
```

This query runs fine.

Now Query 2 (the only thing changed is the security_id param):

`explain select SECURITY_ID, min(EFF_DATE) as startDate, max(EFF_DATE) as endDate from idx_weight where security_id = 26622`:

```
+----+-------------+------------+------+----------------------+--------+---------+-------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type | possible_keys        | key    | key_len | ref   | rows     | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+------+----------------------+--------+---------+-------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | idx_weight | ref  | BPK_AK,idx_weight_ix | BPK_AK | 8       | const | 10700002 | Using index |
+----+-------------+------------+------+----------------------+--------+---------+-------+----------+-------------+
```

<s>Notice that it picks up the index `BPK_AK`, and the actual query runs for over 1 minute.</s>

This is incorrect. Second time took over 10 seconds. I'm guessing the first time the index is not in the buffer pool.

I can get a workaround by appending `group by security_id`:

`explain select SECURITY_ID, min(EFF_DATE) as startDate, max(EFF_DATE) as endDate from idx_weight where security_id = 26622 group by security_id`:

```
+----+-------------+------------+-------+----------------------+---------------+---------+------+-------+---------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys        | key           | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                                 |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+----------------------+---------------+---------+------+-------+---------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | idx_weight | range | BPK_AK,idx_weight_ix | idx_weight_ix | 8       | NULL | 10314 | Using where; Using index for group-by |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+----------------------+---------------+---------+------+-------+---------------------------------------+
```

But I still don't understand why would mysql not picking `idx_weight_ix` for some `security_id`, which is a covering index for this query (and a lot cheaper). Any idea?

=========================================================================

Update:
@oysteing 
Learned a new trick, cool! :)

Here's the optimizer trace:

Query 1: https://gist.github.com/aping/c4388d49d666c43172a856d77001f4ce

Query 2: https://gist.github.com/aping/1af5504b428ca136a8b1c41c40d763e4

And some extra information that might be useful:

From `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS`:

```
+------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
| NON_UNIQUE | INDEX_NAME    | SEQ_IN_INDEX | COLUMN_NAME | CARDINALITY |
+------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
|          0 | BPK_AK        |            1 | SECURITY_ID |       74134 |
|          0 | BPK_AK        |            2 | CONS_ID     |      638381 |
|          0 | BPK_AK        |            3 | EFF_DATE    |    68945218 |
|          1 | idx_weight_ix |            1 | SECURITY_ID |       61393 |
|          1 | idx_weight_ix |            2 | EFF_DATE    |      238564 |
+------------+---------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
```

`CARDINALITY` for `SECURITY_ID` are different, but technically they should be exactly the same, am I right?

From this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49656/find-the-size-of-each-index-in-a-mysql-table?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

```
+---------------+-------------------+
| index_name    | indexentry_length |
+---------------+-------------------+
| BPK_AK        |        1376940279 |
| idx_weight_ix |         797175951 |
+---------------+-------------------+
```

The index size is about 800MB vs 1.3GB.

Running `select count(*) from idx_weight where security_id = 1782` returns `509994`

and `select count(*) from idx_weight where security_id = 26622` returns `5828054`

Then force using `BPK_AK` for query 1:

`select SQL_NO_CACHE SECURITY_ID, min(EFF_DATE) as startDate, max(EFF_DATE) as endDate from idx_weight use index (BPK_AK) where security_id = 1782` took 0.2 sec.

So basically, `26622` has 10 times more rows than `1782`, but using the same index, it took 50 times more time.

PS: buffer pool size is 25GB.

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Comment: Forgot to mention, 5.6

Comment: I am not sure what is happening here. If you can you provide the optimizer trace for the query, I should be able to see what is going on. See http://oysteing.blogspot.com/2016/01/how-to-get-optimizer-trace-for-query.html for advice on how to get the optimizer trace.

Comment: @oysteing uploaded the optimizer trace, and some new observation. Please see the main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optimizer traces shows that the reason for the difference in the selection of index, is due to the estimates received from InnoDB.  For each potential index, the optimizer asks the storage engine for an estimate on how many records are in the range.  For the first query it gets the following estimates:

```
BPK_AK:       1031808
idx_weight_ix: 887856
```

So the estimated read cost is lowest for idx_weight_ix, and this index is chosen. For the second query the estimates are:

```
BPK_AK:        11092112
idx_weight_ix: 12003098
```

And the estimated read cost of BPK_AK is lowest due to the lower number of rows .  You could say that MySQL should know that the real number of rows in the range is the same in both cases, but that logic has not been implemented.

I do not know the details of how InnoDB computes this estimates, but it basically does two "index dives" to find the first and last row in the range, and then somehow computes the "distance" between the two.   It could be that the estimates are affected by unused space in index pages, and that OPTIMIZE TABLE could fix this, but running OPTIMIZE TABLE will probably take very long on such a large table.

The quickest way to solve this, is to add a GROUP BY clause as mentioned by a few other people here.  Then MySQL will only need to read 2 rows per group; the first and the last since index is ordered by EFF_DATE for each value of security_id.  Alternatively, you could use FORCE INDEX to force a particular index.

It may also be that MySQL 8.0 will handle this query better.  The cost model has change somewhat, and it will put higher cost on "cold" indexes that are not cached in the buffer pool.

Answer (score 1):

When you mix normal columns (SECURITY_ID) and aggregate functions (min & max in your case), you should use the GROUP BY. If you do not, MySQL is free give any result it pleases. With GROUP BY, you will get the correct result. Newer MySQL databases force this behavior by default.

The reason the second index is not selected when you leave out the GROUP BY, is most likely due to the fact that the aggregate functions are not limited into the same group (=security_id) abd therefore cannot be used as limiter.

Comment: You're right, a `group by` is more accurate in this query (and with default `sql_mode` since 5.6, this query should return an error). However, I'm still curious why mysql picks different index given different `security_id`. Again, whatever `security_id` is, the result can be obtained by `idx_weight_ix (SECURITY_ID,EFF_DATE)` alone, without touching the primary key at all. Why bother with the other index (`BPK_AK (SECURITY_ID,CONS_ID,EFF_DATE)`), which just has an extra useless column in it?

Comment: Plus, my problem is not mysql giving different/wrong/random result without a `group by`, but using different indices with the seemingly same query, and huge execution time difference (0.5 sec vs 70+ secs).

Comment: When you use the query without the group by, the database can use just the first column in the index. Therefore both indexes (BPK_AK and idx_weight_ix) will be equal candidates. Sometimes query optimizers just make non-optimal choises, especially in cases which are seemingly wrong queries as the developers have not spent time on those.

Comment: @slaakso - Most of what you say is negated by the `WHERE` clause specifying a single `security_id`.  However, the Optimizer may not hav noticed that.

Comment: @RickJames - Optimizer does notice the `security_id`. That it why it is picking the indexes where the column is the first one. The problem with omitting the `GROUP BY` is that the `EFF_DATE` cannot be fetched from the index in any meaningful way. When the `GROUP BY` is added (as it should), `EFF_DATE`'s are "under" `security_id`.

Answer (score 0):

> I can get a workaround by appending group by security_id

Well, yes. I wouldn't do it any other way, since when you use aggregate functions you NEED to group by something. I didn't even know that MySQL allowed you to work around it.

I think @slaakso is right. Upvote him.